# Python: Elegant way to iterate over list to fill numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm searching a more elegant way to do the following:

```
filled_list = [1, 3, 54, 2, 8]
new_list = []

for k in filled_list:
     new_k = # do some stuff
     new_list.append(new_k)

converted_array = np.array(new_list)
```

- iterate over a list, but not with an index
- the new numpy array will have exactly the same amount of entries as in the new_list
- the conversion at the end is not pretty in my eyes and I want to prevent this, ideally by starting with a numpy array. But then I would need to iterate over indices, which I don't want (because it makes the code more bulky)

edit: Example of some stuff

```
# previously filled: dict1, dict2, dict3, common_keys_of_all_dicts

list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []
for k in common_keys_of_all_dicts:
   list1.append(dict1[k].item1)
   list2.append(dict2[k].item2)
   list3.append(dict3[k].item3)
array1 = np.array(list1)
...
```

Comment: This might be easier to answer if you give some hints on what `# do some fancy stuff` means

Comment: At some step or another, either implicitly or explicitly, you will have to convert the list to a numpy array because you are starting with a list. The question then would be, whether you convert to a numpy array first and then *vectorize* the "fancy stuff" operation, or stick to the current format.

Comment: @yatu how does this matter?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I would love to start with a numpy array, edit the question, hopefully it gets more clear now.

Comment: `converted_array = np.fromiter((fancy_stuff(k) for k in filled_list), dtype=...)`? Why do you say you'd have to iterate over indices if it is a numpy array? What is the fancy stuff?

Comment: Alright, in that case the answer really depends on the "fancy operation" itself. This *will* be easier to answer if you give some hints on the operation itself, as yatu said.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I can't give a real answer to this because this varies. I find this type of code snippet frequently in my scripts and was wondering how to improve this in general

Comment: @tomjn This looks like an answer I was looking for. Is there something similar where you do not have to put fancy stuff into a separate function? And if you post this as  a answer instead of a comment, I can mark it ;-)

Comment: @Maikefer As others say it really depends what you want to do with fancy stuff and it would be really helpful to get one or two examples of what you want to do. If you don't need to put it in a function then it probably isn't that fancy!

Comment: By speaking in general terms, you're essentially taking the "worst case" scenario of numpy arrays. *The* main point of numpy arrays is that it enables vectorization (which frankly is a very vast topic). So, if you had to ask for general advice, i'd say: don't iterate, write vectorized logic, and then you can start with an array. As you can see, that is vague because the question itself is too broad. Note that we can't provide a vectorized answer that works in every case, because such a thing doesn't always exist. The generator expression is just "hiding" the iteration, but it's still there.

Comment: tl;dr explore vectorization, and there's no silver bullet out there.

Answer (score 0):

Without a clear definition of some stuff, I´d go with:

```
def somestuff(k):
    return k * 42

converted_array = np.array([somestuff(k) for k in filled_list])
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't work with your starting list as list-type. Directly create `filled_list` as a numpy array and perform all your operations directly at the array. Usually all typs of mathematical stuff can be done directly on the array. Even more complex stuff are facilitated by numpy directly. And if really necessary, you can iterate the numpy array.

For example:

```
filled_list = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
result = filled_list * filled_list + 1    #vectorized manipulation

for x in np.nditer(filled_list):          #iteration over array
    x = #do stuff here
```

I just saw that the author added an example that would not work with an initial numpy-array. So this answer might be already obsolete.

Comment: iteration on arrays is an anti-pattern, avoid iterations.

Comment: True, but sometimes you cannot put everything in a single expression for a vectorized array manipulation.

Comment: Why do you suggest `nditer`?  Does that do something that a plain `for x in filled_list:` can't?

Comment: Well, I have never iterated over an numpy array, so I just searched for it on stackoverflow. That was the suggested way.  Don't know whether a numpy a array can be easily iteratet like lists are.

Comment: Yes, they can, @RaJa.